# how to enable debug on node.js and mongoDB native driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, logging, node-mongodb-native

i use node.js and node-mongodb-native driver, with connection pooling. is there any way to enable debug for see what's happening, how many connections are active and when a connection is opened or closed?

i would like to see something like:

```
* connection xxx opened on host:port
* connection yyy opened on host:port
* connection xxx closed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Db()`](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html) and [`Server()`](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/server.html) objects both support a logger option, which is an object with `log`, `error` and `debug` functions. The `Db()` option doesn't appear to be documented at the moment, but it is mentioned in the [0.9.6-20 2011-10-04 changelog entry](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/changelog/changelog.html).

I'm not sure if all of the information you need is supported with this interface, but it's definitely a good place to start. The driver team would also probably welcome a pull request to add such features.

Comment: thank you, i modified connection.js to log connections and pulled a request on github

Comment: How did you get this working? I passed on an object supporting those methods that should log to the console but I'm not seeing didly squat.

Comment: If it helps, the pull request was: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/pull/765

Answer (score 4):

1. To watch the commands been sent to MongoDB, set the [driver logger's](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/reference/management/logging/) level to `debug`.
2. To react to [connection pool events](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/reference/management/cmap-monitoring/#overview-of-cmap-events), just subscribe to them and log yourself.
3. You may need the [topology monitoring](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/reference/management/sdam-monitoring/) to react to changes of topology, such as joins to a secondary or disconnections with a replica set.

```js
const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/', {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  loggerLevel: 'debug',
  // logger: (message, context) => console.dir(context),
})

// connection pool monitoring
client.on('connectionPoolCreated', event => console.dir(event))
client.on('connectionPoolClosed', event => console.dir(event))
client.on('connectionCreated', event => console.dir(event))
client.on('connectionReady', event => console.dir(event))
client.on('connectionClosed', event => console.dir(event))
client.on('connectionCheckOutStarted', event => console.dir(event))
client.on('connectionCheckOutFailed', event => console.dir(event))
client.on('connectionCheckedOut', event => console.dir(event))
client.on('connectionCheckedIn', event => console.dir(event))
client.on('connectionPoolCleared', event => console.dir(event))

// topology monitoring
client.on('serverDescriptionChanged', event => console.dir(event))
client.on('serverHeartbeatStarted', event => console.dir(event))
client.on('serverHeartbeatSucceeded', event => console.dir(event))
client.on('serverHeartbeatFailed', event => console.dir(event))
client.on('serverOpening', event => console.dir(event))
client.on('serverClosed', event => console.dir(event))
client.on('topologyOpening', event => console.dir(event))
client.on('topologyClosed', event => console.dir(event))
client.on('topologyDescriptionChanged', event => console.dir(event))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the node's driver `Logger` class:

```
import { Logger } from "mongodriver";
```

And later in your code:

```
Logger.setLevel("debug");
```

You can check documentation on [the official driver API doc](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Logger.html)